# Why pygame screen won´t refresh until I move the window arround?

Tags: python, pygame

I´m a newbie on pygame, and i have this code for trying to do kind of a startscreen for a football game, this start screen has a static background image that is"img_start_screen" and the logo of the game that I want it to have a little animation that stops when it reaches the certain point on the screen, that logo is the variable "logo"

```
import pygame,sys
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((1280,720))
pygame.display.set_caption("CEFoot 3.0")
FPS=60
fpsClock=pygame.time.Clock()
img_start_screen=pygame.image.load("start_screen.gif")   
logo=pygame.image.load("logo8bit.png")
logox=390
logoy=0
direction="down"
while True:
    window.blit(img_start_screen,(0,0))
    if direction == "down":
        logoy+=5
        if logoy==300:
            direction="center"
    if direction == "center":
        pass

    screen.blit(logo,(logox,logoy))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    pygame.display.update
    fpsClock.tick(FPS)
```

The problem is that when I run the code it starts as a black screen and not until I move the window "out" of the Windows screen it refreshes, the images aren´t the problem as I ran the code without them and it showed the same black screen. I´m beginning to think that it isn´t code problem but compability as I´m running Python 3.2 and Pygame 1.9(I think) the last version that is really old , all this on Windows 10, so this might be the problem.Thanks in advance.

Comment: parentheses on `update` ?

Comment: ^^ pygame.display.update()

Comment: Yes I just realized it was that, thank you, such a newbie mistake haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know pygame.display.update is a function
as seen if you print it:

```
>>> print pygame.display.update
<built-in function update>
```

so when you call pygame.display.update without parenthesis () you are merely stating a reference to a function. Whereas if you use parenthesis you call the function:

```
>>> print pygame.display.update()
None
```

this calls the function and returns `None`